# Как объединить условия в одно

Tags: c++

Задание:
Составить программу "Список студентов группы", в котором указаны - Фамилия,Имя,пол, место рождения, год рождения.
Нужно сформировать файлы:

1. Список юношей,родившихся в городе название которого вводится с клавиатуры
2. Список девушек
3. Список студентов, родившихся в году, который вводится с клавиатуры.
   файлы упорядочить.

---

Мой вопрос такой- Как мне сделать одновременное использование двух условий с объектом.
То есть использование функции, нахождения только мальчиков и нужного города.
Вот сам код, функции с объектом все есть( они закомментированы)

---

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct Student //Структура Студент 
{
    char Family[35]; //Фамилия студента 
    char Name[35]; //Имя студента 
    char Sex[20]; //Пол студента 
    char City[100]; //Город рождения студента 
    int Date[3]; //Дата рождения студента 
    void Show(); //Функция будет отображать данные студента 
    void Input(); //Функция ввода данных в структуру 
    void Gorod();// Город
    void Year(const int Date1, const int Date2);//год
};

void Student::Input()
{

    cout << "\n\n";

    cout << "Family\t\t";
    cin.getline(Family, 35); //Считали фамилию 


    cout << "Name \t\t";
    cin.getline(Name, 35); //Считали имя 

    int k;
    cout << "Sex chouse 1=Male ,2 =Female \t\t";//Выбираем пол 
    cin >> k;
    if (k == 1)
        strcpy(Sex, "Male");
    else
        strcpy(Sex, "Female");

    cout << "Date born\t";

    cin >> Date[0]; 
    //cin.ignore(); 

    cin >> Date[1];
    //cin.ignore(); 

    cin >> Date[2];
    cin.ignore();


    cout << "City\t\t";
    cin.getline(City, 100);

    cout << "\n\n";

    cout << "======================\n";
}
void Student::Show() //Функция показывает данные структуры на экране 
{
  cout << Name << " " << Family << "\n" << "Sex: " << Sex << "\nBorn in " << Date[0] << "." << Date[1] << "." << Date[2] << "\n";
    cout << "In the city which is called " << City << "\n\n";
}

void Student::Gorod()
{

    char s1[20];
    cout << "\nВедите нужный город:";
    gets(s1);
    if (strcmp(s1, City) == 0)
    {
        cout << "\nГорода одинаковые записываем в файл" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nГорода разные не записываем в файл" << endl;
    }
}
void Student::Year(const int Date1, const int Date2) //Внутри функции ничего менять не планируется, поэтому константы 
{
    if ((Date[2]>Date1) && (Date[2]<Date2)) Show(); //Проверка принадлежности диапазону и при вхождении в диапазон вывод элемента структуры на экран 
};
int prompt_menu_item()
{
    // Выбранный вариант меню
    int variant;
    cout << "Choose you variant\n" << endl;
    cout << "1. Men born in towns\n"           //список юношей родившихся в городе, вводим с клавы
        << "2. Only girls\n"                   //только девушки
        << "3. All students born in years\n"   //список всех студентов родившихся в годах с какого то по какой то, вводим с клавы
        << "4. Open file\n" << endl;
    cout << ">>> ";
    cin >> variant;
    return variant;
}

    int main()
    {
       ////////ЭТО НУЖНЫЕ ФУНКЦИИ//
       //for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) Student[i].Show(); //С помощью цикла показываем заполненную структуру на экране, вызывая метод структуры. 

       //for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) Student[i].Gorod();// C помощью цикла показываем нужные города 

       //for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
       // if (strcmp(Student[i].Sex, "Male") == 0) 
       // Student[i].Show(); //С помощью цикла показываем всех мальчиков. 

       //for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
       // if (strcmp(Student[i].Sex, "Female") == 0) 
       // Student[i].Show(); //С помощью цикла показываем всех девочек.
       ///////////////////
       const int N = 2; //Количество элементов в структуре 
       Student Student[N]; //Структура студентов из N элементов. (Справа объект, слева тип) 

       for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) Student[i].Input(); //С помощью цикла заполняем структуру, вызывая метод структуры. 

       setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
       int variant = prompt_menu_item();

       switch (variant)
       {
          case 1:
             for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                if (strcmp(Student[i].Sex, "Male") == 0)
                   Student[i].Show()&& for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) Student[i].Gorod();
            system("pause");
          break;

          int o, p; cout << "Enter need yaers\t"; cin >> o; cin >> p; // ввод нужных годов 
          for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) Student[i].Year(o, p); //Выводим студентов, которые родились в нужные года 
          cin.get();
          system("pause");
       }
    }
```

Comment: Блин, так и не понял как нормально код вставить.

Comment: Два условия объединяются в одно условие с помощью логического оператора AND ( И ), который обозначается как &&.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Вот я делаю дает ошибку.
case 1:
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
   if (strcmp(Student[i].Sex, "Male") == 0 && Student[i].Gorod)
    Student[i].Show;
  system("pause");
  break;

Comment: @BalinMisha Уберите весь ненужный код, оставьте только то что носится к вопросу и отформатируйте (там 4 ведущих отступа нужно чтобы подсветка включилась)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow я его вроде вставил, но как нужно не получается, чтобы работал

Answer (score 2):

Вот примеры того как объединять несколько условий в одно, переделайте их для себя

```
struct Car
{
    enum Types
    {
          SEDAN
        , HATCHBACK
        , UNIVERSAL
        , COUPE             
    };

    Types Type;
    char  Model[16];
    int   Speed;
};

#define CARS_COUNT (128)

Car cars[CARS_COUNT];

// считаем что массив с машинами как-то заполнен

// 1. выводим модели всех седанов со скоростью большей или равной 120 и меньшей 160
for(int i = 0; i < CARS_COUNT; ++i)   // для каждой машины из массива
{
    if(    Car::SEDAN == cars[i].Type     // тип равен седан
        &&        120 <= cars[i].Speed    // и скорость больше или равно 120
        &&        160 >  cars[i].Speed )  // и скорость меньше 160
    {
       // если все логическое выражение в if вычисляется в true
       // попадаем в этот блок и выводим модель
       std::cout << cars[i].Model << "\n"; 
    }
}

// 2. подсчитываем количество хатчбеков и купе со скоростью 150
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < CARS_COUNT; ++i)
{
    if(  (   Car::HATCHBACK == cars[i].Type     // тип равен хетчбек
          || Car::COUPE     == cars[i].Type )   // или тип равен купе
       && 150 == cars[i].Speed                ) // и скорость равна 150
    {
       ++count;
    }
}
std::count << "\ncount = " << count << "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Я конечно не C програмист но

```
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
     if (strcmp(Student[i].Sex, "Male") == 0) 
     Student[i].Show(); //С помощью цикла показываем всех мальчиков. 
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
     if (strcmp(Student[i].Sex, "Female") == 0) 
     Student[i].Show(); //С помощью цикла показываем всех девочек.
   }
```

одному мне кажется что студенты могут быть либо мальчиком либо девочкой. ну да ладно у вас проблема скорее всего в синтаксисе где то не там стоит скобка `(` `)` или `{` `}` так как вы не соблюдаете никакого coding style то я думаю лучше вам все `if` `for` и д.р. операторы привести к виду `if() { }` и т.д. тогда будет что то видно. Вы сказали ошибка какого вида?

и как понять код ниже

```
 case 1:
             for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                if (strcmp(Student[i].Sex, "Male") == 0)
                   Student[i].Show()&& for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) Student[i].Gorod();
            system("pause");
          break;
```

заходим в case 1 выполняем `for` потом в `if` и чтобы нормальные скобки не ставить показываем студента а после выполняем в `for` показ города?